# Design pattern for multiples methods using same argument

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have this class on which I have a method and will return a map, using dozens of methods inside it using the same arguments.

My class has thousand of lines and it will increase even more.

I can create several classes and inside create methods, but I´m asking if there is a special design for this scenario

**Actual Scenario:**

```
public Map<String, Object> transformMapOnAnotherMap(Map<String, Object> firstMap) {

   Map<String, Object> lastMap = new HashMap<String, Object>(firstMap);

   lastMap = do1(firstMap, lastMap);

   lastMap = do2(firstMap, lastMap);

   lastMap = do3(firstMap, lastMap);

   lastMap = do4(firstMap, lastMap);

   //more 20 methods

   return lastMap;

}
```

**Try without design:**

```
public Map<String, Object> transformMapOnAnotherMap(Map<String, Object> firstMap) {

    Map<String, Object> lastMap = new HashMap<String, Object>(firstMap);

    Do1 do1 = new Do1();
    lastMap = do1.do1(firstMap, lastMap);

    Do2 do2 = new Do2();
    lastMap = do2.do2(firstMap, lastMap);

    // more 20 methods

    return lastMap;

}
```

Comment: Are `do1`, etc., meant to be public, or are they just implementation?

Comment: they´re just implementation

Comment: One option is the [Visitor pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/visitor)

Answer (score 2):

If `do1`, etc., are just implementation, not part of the public interface of your class, it would probably make sense to create a private class (perhaps even a nested one) with a constructor accepting the two maps which it retains as instance variables:

```
private static class Worker {
    Worker(Map firstMap, Map secondMap) {
        this.firstMap = firstMap;
        this.secondMap = secondMap;
    }
    void do1() {
        // ...update `this.lastMap` if appropriate...
    }
    void do2() {
        // ...update `this.lastMap` if appropriate...
    }
}
```

There I've made `Worker` `static` so it's a static nested class, not an inner class, but it could be an inner class instead (no `static`) if you need access to the internals of the surrounding class.

Then

```
public Map<String, Object> transformMapOnAnotherMap(Map<String, Object> firstMap) {
     Worker worker = new Worker(firstMap, new HashMap<String, Object>(firstMap));
     worker.do1();
     worker.do2();
     worker.do3();
     worker.do4();
     //more 20 methods
     return worker.lastMap;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `interface` and make every "do" an implementation of functional interface.

```
interface Do {
    Map<String, Object> apply(Map<String, Object> firstMap, Map<String, Object> lastMap);
}
```

Then you can initialize static `do`s:

```
static Do[] allDos = {
    (firstMap, lastMap) -> {
        // do0
    },
    (firstMap, lastMap) -> {
        // do1
    },
    // ...do2, do3, ...
};
```

If you need to invoke `do0 -> do2 -> do4` for example:

```
public Map<String, Object> transformMapOnAnotherMap(Map<String, Object> firstMap) {
    Map<String, Object> lastMap = new HashMap<String, Object>(firstMap);
    int[] ids = { 0, 2, 4 };
    for (int id : ids)
        lastMap = allDos[id].apply(firstMap, lastMap);
    return lastMap;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't take more functional approach?

define interface

```
interface MapTransformation{ 
     void transformation(Map<String, Object>  first, Map<String, Object>  last);
}
```

then during class creation, class which has definition of `transformMapOnAnotherMap` takes list of transformations as parameter then you could do

```
class SomeClass {

    final private List<MapTransformation> transformations;

    //constructor omitted 

    public Map<String, Object> transformMapOnAnotherMap(Map<String, Object> firstMap) {

        Map<String, Object> lastMap = new HashMap<String, Object>(firstMap);
        transformations.forEach(t->t.transformation(firstMap,lastMap);
        return lastMap;

    }
}
```